# Vash view engine gives always an error when rendering using nodejs & express 3

Tags: node.js, viewengine, vash

I'm using the view engine [vash](https://github.com/kirbysayshi/vash) with nodejs & express 3 and my index.vash and layout are looking as follows:

```
// index.vash
@html.extend('layout', function(model){
    @html.block('body', function(model){
        <span class="name">Welcome</span>
    })
})

// layout.vash
<p>
    @html.block('body')
</p>
```

app.js:

```
app.get('/', function (req, res) {
    res.render('index');
});
```

In app.js I set the view engine: `app.set('view engine', 'vash');`
So these examples are 1:1 the same as described on github.

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23407173/node-js-rendering-error-with-vash) question is the same, except that the solution didn't work for me. He suggests that you should give the correct path to layout.vash, but I got the two vash files (index & layout) in the same directory 'views'. I also tried `@html.extend('views/layout'..` but that didn't work either.

Every time I run the project it displays the following error for index.vash:

> Express
>     500 TypeError: Problem while rendering template at line 5, character 1.
>     Original message: object is not a function.
>     Context:
>     
>     
>     3 | @html.block('body', function(model){
>     4 | Welcome
>     -> 5 | })
>     6 | })
>     
>     at C:\Users\Luca\Documents\VSProjects\Website\TestApp\TestApp\node_modules\vash\build\vash.js:2213:4
>     at Object.vash.loadFile (C:\Users\Luca\Documents\VSProjects\Website\TestApp\TestApp\node_modules\vash\build\vash.js:2072:10)
>     at helpers.extend (C:\Users\Luca\Documents\VSProjects\Website\TestApp\TestApp\node_modules\vash\build\vash.js:2190:8)
>     at eval (eval at (C:\Users\Luca\Documents\VSProjects\Website\TestApp\TestApp\node_modules\vash\build\vash.js:1820:24), :17:21)
>     at linked (C:\Users\Luca\Documents\VSProjects\Website\TestApp\TestApp\node_modules\vash\build\vash.js:1860:12)
>     at C:\Users\Luca\Documents\VSProjects\Website\TestApp\TestApp\node_modules\vash\build\vash.js:2082:21
>     at Object.vash.loadFile (C:\Users\Luca\Documents\VSProjects\Website\TestApp\TestApp\node_modules\vash\build\vash.js:2070:10)
>     at View.vash.renderFile [as engine] (C:\Users\Luca\Documents\VSProjects\Website\TestApp\TestApp\node_modules\vash\build\vash.js:2078:8)
>     at View.render (C:\Users\Luca\Documents\VSProjects\Website\TestApp\TestApp\node_modules\express\lib\view.js:76:8)
>     at Function.app.render (C:\Users\Luca\Documents\VSProjects\Website\TestApp\TestApp\node_modules\express\lib\application.js:504:10)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally solved the problem, the path was not correct in index.vash when calling extend, I just had to add a trailing slash ("/layout").

Answer (score 0):

In my case, i was migrating a project from MVC to Node/Vash.
And the Vash layout file had some commented MVC code, which led to the rendering problem.